# Grails FindAllBy returns list with null objects

Tags: hibernate, grails, findall

we had the following line in our log:
**java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot get property ''parentId'' on null object**

I cannot explain how the object can be null.
We are using Grails and have the following short example source code:

```
List<Jobs> jobs = Jobs.findAllByCustomerIdAndValidThruAndReferenceId(session.customer.id, null, reference.id)
    for (Jobs job : jobs) {
        def parentId = job.parentId == null ? job.id : job.parentId
        [...]
    }
```

Yes, its not more than that. 
Afaik findAll will return null when nothing is found and it won't execute the foreach loop.
If it finds some results there will be a list of objects like [Jobs, Jobs, Jobs].
Refering to the exception there must be a list like [Jobs, null, null, Jobs] or similiar.

So the main question is: Is there a possibility that Grails or Hibernate will give a list containing null objects with findAll? How is this even possible and do we have do hardening this by checking if an object is null?

I couldn't find this problem anywhere else and I also could not reproduces/debug this problem locally.

Thank you

Comment: It looks more likely that `requirement` is null, as I don't see it defined in your snippet.

Comment: sry, mistaken by me and corrected. I tried to shorten the source and used just a wrong, irritating name. Thanks for correction.

Comment: Have you run through in debug mode?  Ensured you're getting a list of `Job`s back at all?  I don't believe you should get null results, but if `reference` is null, then you'd get a NPE on the `findAll()` (or if `session.customer` is null)